# $+$- and $\Sigma$-types in modal type theory

Tags: type-theory, modal-logic

I am reading Bierman & de Paiva's [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1005291931660) on intuitionistic modal logic. They offer a typed version on page 401. I wonder whether the result generalizes to $\Sigma$- and $+$-types in Martin-Löf type theory. In particular, I wonder whether the **T**-rule $\Box A\rightarrow A$ generalizes to the two mentioned types. In other words, can we have the following rules?

$$\Box (A+B)\rightarrow (A+B),\quad\quad\quad\Box\Sigma x:A.B(x)\rightarrow\Sigma x:A.B(x).$$

Comment: Typically that rule holds irrespective of $A$. What would be more in question is how $\square$ can be distributed across those connectives. I suppose, if you are questioning because those are not 'propositions', then there are modal type theories that have modalities for non-propositional types, and they would have that rule for said types.

Comment: @DanDoel In their paper, it appears that they deal with traditional intuitionistic logic. So, I think they should require that $A$ be proof-irrelevant. But since $A+B$ and $\Sigma x:A.B(x)$ are typical types that are proof-relevant, can we, for example, obtain a pair of proofs for $\Sigma x:A.B(x)$ from $\Box\Sigma x:A.B(x)$?

Comment: @DanDoel Yes, exactly. I am worried about whether they must be propositions. Do you have references for modal type theories for non-propositional types? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll leave an answer with some possibilities, because it's probably too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a bit of research on modalities in type theory, but I'm uncertain what exactly what you're looking for.

I think some of the oldest stuff would be by Frank Pfenning and Rowan Davies. I believe they develop modal type theory with a view toward staged computataion, where $\square A$ is like an internal classification of closed terms of type $A$. I'm not sure if any of their work has $Σ$ and $+$ specifically, but once that is your mindset, it's not much of a surprise that $\square A → A$ works for them (you get an $A$ value by actually reducing the $\square A$ term).

If you're looking to read about modal type theory from the ground up, I'd look into their work, because it's probably the simplest to start with. [A Judgmental Reconstruction of Modal Logic](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/papers/mscs00.pdf) might be a good precursor. [A Modal Analysis of Staged Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/papers/jacm00.pdf) should get into some of the ideas I was talking about above. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with all their work on the subject, so there might be additional/better papers I'm not aware of.

If you merely want to *see* something like MLTT with modalities, I found [this](https://jozefg.github.io/papers/2019-implementing-modal-dependent-type-theory.pdf). It uses a different presentation, though, and looks quite a bit more complex. Of course, some of that complexity is due to questions that necessarily arise with dependent types and modalities (like, how should equality/identity act for values of modal type). If you get really interested in modal type theory, there is also [this](https://jozefg.github.io/papers/type-theory-a-la-mode.pdf) which seems like a pretty comprehensive treatment of certain sorts of modal type theories (unfortunately, 'modality', is a vague enough term that it's impossible to concretely describe a generalized framework encompassing modal theories; also unfortunately, I haven't gotten around to reading it thoroughly yet, but it seems great).

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.